# Google chart convert to image when button is click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I finally managed to get screenshot with Google Chart working in Chrome,IE,FF.

In order to get google chart working in screenshot i have to convert it to image. But  then animation,tooltip or crosshair wont work. Currently i am using setTimeout to get the animation working for 5sec.

Can anyone help fix this part with button click, so when i click the button image gets convert and screenshot is taken.

*how to do this **Button  click so two function triggers one in jquery another in javasrcipt**.*

button click:

```
<a href="#" onclick="someFunc()">Save Form</a>
<script>
function someFunc() {
    google();
    capture();
}
</script>
```

google draw:

```
google.visualization.events.addListener(chart2, 'ready', function() {
//currently using settimeout here
    curve_chart.innerHTML = '<img src="' + chart2.getImageURI() + '">';
    console.log(curve_chart.innerHTML);

});
```

capture:

```
<script>
 $(function() { 
//how to make someFunc() work here. ?
   $("#btnSave").click(function() { 
        html2canvas($("#cal"), {
            //screenshot code here
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Its been days trying to figure out screenshot. now animation,tooltip wont work. 
Advance Thanks .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there is better way, please let me know. Thanks.

Solved the Div with Google chart issue using global variable.

Like:

freeze=0;//global variable

---

*Div Screenshot button click- with three functions :*

freeze=1;

// delay

drawChart(); // this is for redraw with chart with freeze = 1;

capture(); // to capture image

---

*In google chart :*

conversion part condition: if freeze = 1 convert part works; else no convert (So i can get cross-hair and tool-tip working.)

google redraws chart with freeze=1

---

*in image capture :*

captures div with google chart,

makes freeze = 0

then again calls drawChart(). so Google chart again draws with freeze=0, so without chart-image convert.